# why I can not put button element while parent have height with percent?

Tags: javascript, css, position

I have a `div` with 15% height (`height: 15%;`)

I can not put set span button of this div. If I use `height: 300px;` it works well. but with percent height does not work. why?

```css
#parent {
  height: 15%;
  position: relative;
}

span { 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You set the parent's height to 15%, but does the parent of `#parent` have a height set? If it does, this should work.

Comment: unable to reproduce please provide a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the height of the body by using 100vh;

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: red;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```